# scipy.misc module has no attribute imresize

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I want to use a part of the code for changing my input image size, but imresize is deprecated on scipy and cant be run on google colab. The part of the code is:

```
height = 256
width  = 256
channels = 3 
.....   
img = sc.imread(Tr_list[idx])
img = np.double(sc.imresize(img, [height, width, channels], interp='bilinear', mode = 'RGB'))
```

so, I'm looking for an equivalent code on numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize()). How exactly should I change my code?

The exact error text is:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'
```

Comment: Please update your post with the exact & full error trace. Plus, since you ask about `numpy`, you should include the tag (edited).

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you should use the `Image` module of `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image
height = 256
width  = 256
...
img = ...
img = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((height, width), Image.BILINEAR)).astype(np.double)
```

Comment: It brings a new error:

ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (256). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)

Comment: try to use the integer digit that the traceback suggests, instead of  PIL.Image.BILINEAR

Comment: Since you imported only `Image` from `PIL`, not the actual `PIL`, you can’t do `PIL.Image.BILINEAR`. Instead, do `Image.BILINEAR`.